# New text line in JavaScript with localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to create some text output from a JS string, but have it on two lines.

My JavaScript:

```
    function checkMessage(element) {
        var aTag= element.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstChild;
        if (element.src == "x.jpg") 
        {
            element.src = "y.jpg";
            var aText = 'First \n Second';
            //aText = aText.replace("<br />", ' ');
            aTag.innerHTML = aText;
            localStorage.setItem(aTag.id, aText);
        }
```

My problem is that for some reason \n isn't working (I read this was JS's alternate to `<br />`), it only seems to add a space. I have tried instead using `'First <br /> Second'` and although this works on the image click, upon the page refreshing, it writes out on one line literally "`First <br /> Second`". I also tried replacing the `<br />` after the click, but it just does as anticipated... removes the line seperation anyway.
Is my issue because of the way localStorage is working?

Additional code info:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    aElements = $('body').find('p').each(function(index, element) {
        storageItem = localStorage.getItem(element.id);
        if (storageItem) {
           $('#' + element.id).text(storageItem);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
foreach ($things as $key => $thing) {
    echo "<div class='grid-container'>";
        echo "<div class='item4'><p id='a$i'>Message</p></div>";
        echo "<div class='item5'><img src='x.jpg' onclick='checkMessage(this)'  /></div>";
    echo "</div>";
    $i ++;
}
```

How do I go about splitting my text into two lines and it staying that way upon refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. You have the args the wrong way round in `replace()`

```
var aText = 'First \n Second';
aText = aText.replace(" \n ", "<br />");
```

First arg is what you want to match and the second is what you want to replace it with.

Also try using `.html()` instead of `.text()` to insert the text. That will parse any HTML in your string, where `.text()` just inserts the literal value.

```
$('#' + element.id).html(storageItem);
```

Comment: Thanks Shaun,
Unfortunately this does for me just as `<br />` did alone. It works perfectly when I click the image - the lines seperate as I desire, but when I hit refresh on the page, the code gets written out in literal, in this case `\n` gets replaces with `<br />` and outputs the text "`First <br /> Second`" on one line.

Comment: Did you try using `.html()` instead of `.text()`?

Comment: Ah! I would not have thought to try this. Such a small change to have fixed my issue. Thank you very much, Shaun!